# Ansible and Template file inserting values in to the template

Tags: python-2.7, templates, dictionary, ansible, jinja2

I'm having issues at the moment I have a map of some aws subnets with their routing tables like so ( example output via ansible) :

```
"subnetwork_route_map": [
    {
        "route_table_id": "rtb-xxxxxx",
        "subnet_id": "subnet-xxxxxx"
    },
    {
        "route_table_id": "rtb-xxxxxx",
        "subnet_id": "subnet-xxxxxxx"
    },
    {
        "route_table_id": "rtb-xxxxxx",
        "subnet_id": "subnet-xxxxxx"
    }
]
```

I wish to  insert these values in to a template file and I thought I could do something like this after seeing a few example:

```
{% for item in subnetwork_route_map %}
{{ item[1]['subnet_id'] }},{{ item[1]['route_table_id'] }}§
{% endfor %}
```

how ever i'm getting an error when I try this I get an error from ansible:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "dict object has no element 1"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subnetwork_route_map` is a *list of dictionaries*, `item` is an individual dictionary, you don't need the `[1]` part:

```
{% for item in subnetwork_route_map %}
    {{ item['subnet_id'] }},{{ item['route_table_id'] }}§
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation that seems to have removed the previous error however I am now receiving the following.  `fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'item' is undefined"}`